# css3 radial gradient and html5 boilerplate template

Tags: css

Ok, so i am trying to figure out why on one of my test pages, that utilizes the html5 boilerplate template... that the css3 radial gradient isnt working for a body background...??

```
   body {
    background-color:#c6c1b8;

background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);

background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);

background-image: -o-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);

background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);

background-image: radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%)
}
```

http://jiujitsuboise.com/2012-Redesign/

I have been using FireBug to diagnose, but cant seem to figure out what is happening??

Comment: your link doesn't go anywhere

Comment: im having the same problem. all i did was start with a fresh copy of the boilerplate and add the gradient css. wtf'ing @ myself

Comment: i removed the stylesheet that came with html5 boilerplate and the gradient is rendering, but incorrectly

Comment: forgot that the body needs to have content before it will be rendered

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I know if you are using IE by any chance css may not work at all. Use mozilla / chrome latest versions to see the css working. It's working on my side
2. or if you want to write it in a class then write like this

Code :

```
`<style type="text/css">
body
{
   background-color:#c6c1b8;
   background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);
   background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);
   background-image: -o-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);
   background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%);
   background-image: radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse closest-side, #c6c1b8 33%,#949089 97%)
}</style> <body style=""> </body>`
```

or write in style attribute of body tag
hope this will work for you :)